# How do I generate IIS machineKey from inside code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, web-config

I want random values for this web.config section:

```
<machineKey validation="HMACSHA512" decryption="AES"
     validationKey="I NEED VALUE FOR THIS" 
     decryptionKey="SOME KEY" />
```

I see that IIS Manager can generate values but in the version I have it has no option for "HMACSHA512" in the dropdown. So I need some other way.

I could write some C# code for that but what should it do exactly? Should it just generate a long enough random number and format that?

Do I just use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class and generate an appropriately long byte array and then format that as hex? Will that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I just use RNGCryptoServiceProvider class and generate an appropriately long byte array and then format that as hex?

Pretty much. That's what the [.NET Framework is doing](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Configuration/MachineKeySection.cs,331) when you set it to `AutoGenerate`.

You can use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to generate an hex value with an appropriate length. HMACSHA512 uses a 512-bit value, which is 64-bytes, or 128 hex characters. So we can do something like this:

```csharp
var rng = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
var buffer = new byte[64];
rng.GetBytes(buffer);
var hmacKey = BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", "");
```